# Proving $\neg A\vee(A\wedge \neg B)= \neg A \vee \neg B$.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How do I prove using boolean algebra that $\neg A\vee(A\wedge \neg B)= \neg A \vee \neg B$?  I can see it in the logic table and it is logical, but I can't prove it mathematically.

Comment: Hi new user. Welcome to MSE! Please share your thoughts so far. Also, you might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Distribute so you get $(\neg A\vee A)\wedge(\neg A\vee \neg B)$ The first is obviously a tautology so you just get $\neg A\vee \neg B$

Answer (score 1):

Here is essentially the answer from [ruler501](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ruler501), but written down in a different notation, and with some more detail.

To prove this equivalence, the simplest approach is to start at the most complex side and try to simplify.  Therefore we calculate:

\begin{align}
& \lnot A \lor (A \land \lnot B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"$\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\land\;$ -- really the only thing we can do"} \\
& (\lnot A \lor A) \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"left hand part: law of the excluded middle, i.e., $\;P \lor \lnot P \equiv \text{true}\;$"} \\
& \text{true} \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify using $\;P \land \text{true} \equiv P\;$"} \\
& \lnot A \lor \lnot B \\
\end{align}

This proves the equivalence.

Comment: I think that can be useful if you add the details for the 2nd and 3rd step, i.e. $\lnot A \lor A \equiv T$ and $T \land P \equiv P$, justified as "immediate" or to be "proved" by truth-table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Done.

Comment: Looks good. It's a good explanation of the justification of every step in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do these via cases because it is a little quicker than truth tables a lot of the time. Suppose $A = T$ then

$$\begin{align}\neg A\vee (A\wedge \neg B) &= F\vee (T\wedge \neg B) \\ &= F\vee \neg B \\ &= \neg A\vee \neg B.\end{align}$$

This follows since $F = \neg A$. Then if $A=F$, we have

$$\begin{align}\neg A\vee(A\wedge \neg B) &= T\vee (F\wedge\neg B) \\ &= T \\ &= \neg A\vee \neg B. \end{align}$$

This follows since $\neg A = T.$ This holds regardless of the truth or falsity of $B$ so they are the same.